# Where is the .railsrc file located in Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running Rails 5.1 on Windows 7 Pro, I'm trying to find the .railsrc file in order to customize new rails apps.  But all the info I find on how to edit this file seems to be for linux systems.  Where is it under Windows?

Comment: what about this ? http://ozmm.org/posts/railsrc.html if you dig into this you understand that in the end `load File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/.railsrc'` is just the command for loading `/.railsrc` file ... so it depends on your `File.dirname(__FILE__)` value where you have to save it 

also share the documentation you read

Comment: I don't think this file is created by default unless you manually create it, so I think no file is present in your system unless you've created it before (then you mostly should know it's location). If you want to create a new one I think you should put it in `C:\Users\<current user>\.railsrc`